# Tips for GIF sizes in Facebook chat bots

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am in the process of launching a facebook chat bot that is pretty gif heavy and have a couple questions.  We are running into load times that are way too slow, especially on mobile.  While I know some of the gifs are way too large and need to be cut down, a lot of the smaller ones were also having this problem, so I was curious if you guys had some tips:

1. What's a good rule of thumb for gif sizes for fb chat bots?  Is there a file size that is best not to exceed? We are having the most trouble loading them on a mobile device.  What's a good size limit for mobile browsers?
2. Does facebook load all the gifs on the backend at once, or does it load them as they get called?  I ask this because if it's loaded all at once in the beginning, having a lot of gifs in there would be an issue i'm guessing.

Anyways thanks for the tips have a great day!

Comment: Are you asking about images for the generic template?

Comment: We are serving gifs as part of the text responses to user interactions.  However we are getting really slow loading times even for gifs that are only along the lines of 5-8mb, especially on mobile.  I was curious if there was a sort of soft rule on "size limit" so as not to bog down the user experience with long gif loading times.  This also applies to regular jpgs ect. as we serve those as well

Comment: There aren't any guidelines, really. Are you getting slow load times for messages that only have one attachment, or is it something like a carousel of generic templates?